# Photo Competition 2021-05-24: In Deep Thought

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: In Deep Thought

Capture a photo of a subject that demonstrates "deep thought", contemplation, intense musing, etc. The subject may be a person or animal, even an inanimate object, so long as the key concept of deep thought is the central focus of the photograph.

**Requirements**

1. The subject of the photo must be in, or appear to be in, deep thought
2. *Should* be a portrait shot of a person, people, or pets/animals

   - Self portraits are allowed
   - Inanimate objects or trees may qualify, but only if they depict deep thought
   - An example might be the contorted silhouette of a tree that emulates a person in deep thought
   - Another example might be a statue, small, large, even huge, that depicts deep thought
3. The *object* of the subject's thought can be anything

   - i.e. Another person
   - i.e. The sky
   - i.e. The relationship between *being* and *time*, wherein each reciprocally determines the other, yet the former cannot be addressed temporally, nor can the the latter be expressed as a being.
   - i.e. Chocolate-pecan pie

This theme was suggested by [Aquarius_Girl](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5205/aquarius-girl).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/124789/photo-competition-2021-05-24-in-deep-thought?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on May 24, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Should I Stay or Should I Fold Now?

[image: Should I Stay or Should I Fold Now?]

One of a group of elderly women playing cards in the park on a beautiful spring day. Wasn't close enough to see what game they were playing. Taken during a street photography trip to Columbus Park, New York, NY.

Nikon D700 with a Nikkor 80-400mm and 2x teleconverter at 700mm. 
ISO 800; 1/500s; f/5 
Captured 2015-05-23

Answer (score 4):

[image]

## "I wonder what that squirrel is up to..."

A shot taken on one of our first lockdown walks in 2020. Kaylee is lying on a fallen over tree, procrastinating.

Location: Black hill near Dundee, Scotland

Date: 2020-03-30

Camera: Panasonic DC-GX9, 12-60@60mm, f/5.6, 1/200 sec, iso 200

Answer (score 4):

**Who are you looking at?** [image: Who are you looking at]

lumix Panasonic gx80,
Vario PZ 14-42 lens
f5.6
41mm
ISO 200

Answer (score 4):

### Furrowed brow

2021-05-15, a German kitchen

Sony DSC-R1, f=58mm (135 eq), f:6.3
[image: Furrowed brow]

Answer (score 3):

### Am I Next?

Los Gatos, CA, March 10th 2021

iPhone 7+

(gelatin is usually made of pigs and cows)

[image]

Comment: For an iphone, that's a pretty good photo.

Answer (score 2):

### Goldfinch Glare

Shoreline Park, Mountain View, March 3rd 2021

Nikon D500 with Sigma 150-600

ISO 898, f/7.1, 1/2000

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Is he coming in for a kiss?

Picture taken in [Kosamphi Forest Park](https://www.tourismthailand.org/Attraction/kosamphi-forest-park), Maha Sarakham, Thailand on April 8th, 2021. Photo taken with my Sony RX10M3 at f/4, shutter time 1/160s at 51.14mm and ISO250.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### What do you mean, *"the zoo has switched to buffet-style dining"*?

Picture taken in [Safari World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_World), Bangkok, Thailand on April 13th, 2021. Photo taken with my Sony RX10M3 at f/4, shutter time 1/50s at 146.76mm and ISO125.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Title:  Foreboding
Camera: Canon Powershot A2300
Date:  October 3, 2019
Location:  New Hampshire, Steam railway
Settings: f/5. Focal length 14.715 mm
[image]